# Stream Videos in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

I have a requirement to upload videos, stream them, and search for them.
It is required that the videos are not public, the Sharepoint site will be secured with a login.
Is this possible with Sharepoint? I read some about ShareTube, but I am not clear.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [Podcasting Kit for SharePoint](http://www.codeplex.com/pks). It might already do what you want to do.